# How to use a global ScreenVisibilityListener class?

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm referring to this page of the official doc: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=listen-to-visibility-events-globally

After I create this class, how I tell navigator to use it?

Comment: In you `app.js` you will instantiate this class and the call `.register()` on the same. Please see this https://github.com/InTeach/react-native-navigation-2/blob/072feac737984f918be90b6ebfa88341b25a8233/src/ScreenVisibilityListener.js and https://github.com/InTeach/react-native-navigation-2/blob/072feac737984f918be90b6ebfa88341b25a8233/example/src/app.js#L8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ScreenVisibilityListener` listens to global events fired on the native side through react-native eventDispatcher, the navigator doesn't need to know about it.

Example usage:

```
import {ScreenVisibilityListener} from 'react-native-navigation';

new ScreenVisibilityListener({
  willAppear: ({screen}) => {
    console.log(`Displaying screen ${screen}`) 
  },
  didAppear: ({screen, startTime, endTime, commandType}) => {
    console.log('screenVisibility', `Screen ${screen} displayed in ${endTime - startTime} millis [${commandType}]`)
  },
  willDisappear: ({screen}) => {
    console.log(`Screen will disappear ${screen}`) 
  },
  didDisappear: ({screen}) => {
    console.log(`Screen disappeared ${screen}`)
  }
}).register();
```